# There seem to be a problem with my javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made some simple code to check usernames and passwords. But it doesn't work. I'm still learning html and started learning javascript like few days ago so can anyone pinpoint the problem and explain why?
It's a small code so here's the whole thing:

```js
function loginCheck() {
  var u = document.form1.u1.value;
  var p = document.form1.p1.value;
  if (u == "us1" and p == "pa1") {
    document.form1.n.disabled = false;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid credentials";
    }
  }
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="get">
  Username: <input type="text" name="u1" size="20"><br><br> 
  Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="p1" size="20"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="loginCheck()"><br><br> 
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="n" size="20" disabled="true">
```

Expected result is:
  if correct, "Enter name" field should be enabled.
  if wrong, the output should be "Invalid credentials".

But nothing's happening

Comment: onclick or oNclick!!!

Comment: i dont think `js` has `and` operator ... did you mean `&`

Comment: Probably not `&` but `&&`.  [read all about logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Start by opening browser dev tools console (F12) and check for errors thrown. You have several issues in code shown

Comment: It should be `&&` instead off `and`, and don't forget a missing `)`in your `alert`.

Comment: code is working, do modification suggested by @chŝdk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function loginCheck() {
  var u = document.form1.u1.value;
  var p = document.form1.p1.value;
  if (u == "us1" && p == "pa1") {
    document.form1.n.disabled = false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Invalid credentials");
  }
}
```

you had **and** instead of **&&** and one missing brackets in alert statement.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing elements directly via the `document` object is very brittle and dependent on all of the surrounding html, what html spec you're using, etc.

It's usually best practice to put an `id` attribute on the form and then reference it via `document.getElementById(yourId)`.

If you are using event handlers though, like you have here. You can access the DOM node where you set the event handler (ie `onclick` location) by inspecting the first argument of your handler, canonically named `event`. You do so through `event.target`.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure it is coming from your function :

```
alert("Invalid credentials";
```

A bracket is missing.

```
alert("Invalid credentials");
```

Check this out !

Answer (score -2):

try onClick="() => loginCheck()" or onClick="loginCheck"
inside if should be && instead of "and"

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginCheck() {
  var u = document.forms["form1"]["u1"].value;
  var p = document.forms["form1"]["p1"].value;
  //alert(u);
  //alert(p);
  if (u == "us1" && p == "pa1") {
    document.getElementById("n").disabled = false;
    return true;
  }else {
    alert("Invalid credentials");
    return false;
  }
}

</script>
<form name = "form1" method = "post" onsubmit="return loginCheck()">
Username: <input type = "text" name = "u1" size = "20"><br><br>
Password: &nbsp;<input type = "password" name = "p1" size = "20"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Login"><br><br>
Enter name: <input id="n" type = "text" name = "n" size = "20" disabled = "true"> 
</form>
```

Comment: code only answers aren't answers IMO - plus this questions problems are typos